# Volatile для согласованности кешей

Tags: c++, кэширование, cpu, информатика

Недавно спорил с преподавателем о причинах возникновения ошибок без использования ключевого слова volatile для использования одной переменной из разных потоков, работающих на разных ядрах. Одна из причин, по его мнению это то, что volatile необходим, чтобы избежать локального кэширования, я же говорил, что современные процессоры используют протоколы синхронизации, обеспечивающие когернтность кэша, кто из нас прав?  [image: конспект]

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что тут ещё уровень оптимизаций будет играть большую роль

Comment: Лучше указать volatile. Трудно представить, что нынешние трансляторы сами поймут, что переменная общая для двух потоков. Потоки это объекты ОС, а нынешние трансляторы ничего не знают об ОС, или знают очень мало.

Comment: @Andrey с этим я не спорю.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Согласен, но вопрос немного про другое. Необходимо ли нам программное решение для когерентности кешей.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что такое "когерентность кешей". Общие переменные для разных потоков должны лежать в общей памяти и (скорее всего) должны быть защищены от одновременного доступа объектами синхронизации типа семафоров. Если общие переменные для разных потоков лежат в локальных кешах разных ядер, то черт его знает что там будет. Вряд-ли ядра будут корректировать свои кеши, если в соседнем ядре модифицировался кеш. Лучше на это не закладываться.

Comment: Вы сказали позицию свою и преподавателя, но не сказали, про что был спор. Необходим ли `volatile`... где?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Ну это проблема состояния гонки, а не кэша. Под когерентностью, я понимаю непротиверечивость данных в следствии использования протоколов синхронизации.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в общем случае, немного поправил вопрос.

Comment: @kaylil_01 Понятнее не стало. :) Догадываюсь, что вопрос про использование одной переменной из разных потоков, но лучше это явно указать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, надеюсь, так лучше.

Comment: Вы правы. На когерентность кэшей `volatile` не влияет, он однозначно говорит компилятору, что при каждом доступе к переменной нужно использовать машинную инструкцию чтения (при обновлении переменной инструкцию записи) из памяти.  К threads это никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Для взаимодействия между потоками подойдет `std::atomic`. Обычные и volatile переменные - нет. См https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557979/when-to-use-volatile-with-multi-threading

Comment: @avp Не могли бы вы составить ответ, чтобы я мог его отметить как решение. И не могли бы вы еще рассказать насчет регистров, насколько я понимаю, у них нет протоколов синхронизация, и volatile для них нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Развею заблуждения о volatile: Наличие или отсутствие volatile в общем случае ничего не говорит об обращении с переменной в плане работы кеша процессора, ровно как и не влияет на (не)корректность использования такой переменной из разных потоков. Доступ к volatile переменной - это одно из четырех базовых действий с побочными эффектами, на обязательное выполнение хотя бы одного из которых по ходу работы потока выполнения может рассчитывать компилятор. Причем семантика этого доступа отдается на откуп реализации.

Развею заблуждения о кеше: Протоколы когерентности кеша заботятся только о когерентности этого самого кеша. Когда гранулированность операций не соответствует гранулированности кеша, разные ядра могут не согласится о результатах такой операции. Пример: на типичной x86 машине возможен доступ к блокам из 8 байт без выравнивания, однако протокол когерентности кеша работает только с выровненными блоками по 64 байт (кеш линия); соответственно при записи в память какой-нибудь переменной volatile long long расположенной на границе двух кеш линий, разные ядра при чтении этой переменной могут получить разные правую или левую части.

Подытожу:

1. обращение к volatile переменной - некоторое действие с побочным эффектом, влияющие на анализ и оптимизацию потока выполнения компилятором, не более
2. volatile не гарантирует корректную работы с переменной из разных потоков
3. volatile не гарантирует, что обращение к переменой должно осуществляться атомарно или хотя бы за одну инструкцию
4. когерентность кеша не гарантирует логическую согласованность операций

Примечание: в vc++ есть [расширение, задающее семантику атомарного доступа при обращении к volatile переменным](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/volatile-volatile-keyword-interpretation?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Как тогда гарантировать когерентность кеша в таких частных случаях?

Comment: @kaylil_01 Когерентность кеша гарантируется всегда. Другое дело, что когерентность кеша не подразумевает атомарность любых операций с памятью. Так что следует писать код строго избегающий состояния гонки, и не надеяться, что когерентный кеш магическим способом позволит избежать проблем рассинхронизации.

Comment: Т.е. в случае, если, допустим переменная больше, чем кэш-линия, то необходим атомарный доступ к ней, я правильно вас понял?

Comment: @kaylil_01 Наоборот, если переменная больше, чем кеш линия, то атомарный доступ к ней будет невозможен или затруднен. Так что потребуется дополнительная синхронизация. Многие атомарные инструкции требуют не только помещения переменной в одной кеш линии, но и выравнивания. Если хотите подробностей, можете почитать [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Developer's Manual: Vol. 3A 8.1.1 Guaranteed Atomic Operations](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html)

Comment: Как тогда гарантировать согласованность операций для переменных больше, чем кэш-линия?

Comment: @kaylil_01 я же написал - дополнительная синхронизация, mutex какой-нибудь

Comment: извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но получается, что volatile нужен только для непереупорядочевания операция?

Comment: @kaylil_01 Скорее только для указания компилятору, что некоторые вычисления имеют побочные эффекты и не должны им выкидываться, даже если они сами по себе не имеют побочных эффектов и конечный результат никак не используется. Для тестов каких-нибудь. Некоторые библиотеки или платформы требуют его использования для специфических целей. Очень редко.

Comment: Пример с переменной, пересекающей границу линий кэша интересен, но что-то у меня не складывается, как сделать тест, который продемонстрирует обновление только части бит переменной (даже в bare metal). Может распишете?

Comment: @avp [пример](https://pastebin.com/sEaUiYVs) у меня работает с vs2019 (/volatile:iso) и gcc7, в разных онлайн ide - не работает, видимо из-за доступности только одного cpu

Comment: OK, попозже скомпилирую `-O3 -S` и посмотрю что там...

Comment: @user7860670, я не собираюсь его запускать. Хочу посмотреть на asm, есть ли внутри `for(;;) {  .... }` чтение из памяти и запись в нее. Из-за этого же весь сыр-бор?

Comment: @user7860670, пардон, я почему-то решил, что это пример, когда обращение к volatile не делает load/store (этот пример читает память  по адресу, передаваемому в `worker()` и пишет новое значение по нему на каждой итерации). А вы сделали пример с пересечением cache line. Я его запустил на I5-2500 4 core  и в самом деле,  вызван Abort (в разных запусках на разных итерациях). / Спасибо, учту влияние  aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы. На когерентность кэшей volatile не влияет и к  threads никакого отношения не имеет.

Этот атрибут переменной однозначно говорит компилятору, что при каждом обращении к переменной по чтению (т.е. когда в программе вы используете текущее значение переменной)
необходимо использовать машинную инструкцию чтения из памяти в регистр процессора, а при каждом ее изменении нужно записать регистр в память.

Естественно, в системах с когерентным кэшем чтение памяти в регистр и запись регистра в память проходит через кэш процессора. Если один процессор обращается к только что измененной  другим процессором памяти (ее новое значение находится в локальном кэше данного процессора), то механизм когерентности обеспечит изменение локального кэша первого процессора. Т.е. он прочтет последнее измененное значение переменной.

Однако, это описание несколько упрощено для современных процессоров, которые могут исполнять инструкции [out-of-order](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Для решения этой проблемы служат *atomic* переменные, которые заставляют компилятор вставлять в код [memory barriers](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8).

Comment: Поставил минус: *"однозначно говорит компилятору..."* - как раз наоборот, семантика volatile может быть очень разной; *"в системах с когерентным кэшем чтение памяти в регистр и запись регистра в память проходит через кэш процессора"* - чтение и (особенно) запись может запросто проходить мимо кеша, не нарушая при этом его когерентности; *"прочтет последнее измененное значение переменной"* - не обязательно

Comment: @user7860670, конечно, не из-за минуса, а ради других читателей, можете привести пример кода с `volatile` при компиляции которого **не будет** load/store при каждом обращении? / Что касается записи мимо кэша, то imho очевидно, что это зависит от атрибутов сегмента памяти в MMU, а программы, который сейчас пишет ТС (и 99% остальных читателей) работают под управлением ОС в shared cached памяти, для которой все чтения-записи идут через write back cache policy

Comment: Не факт, что эти load/store будут занимать именно одну машинную инструкцию, и что там не будет чего-то еще. Что касается записи мимо кеша, то 99% читателей вполне себе могут использовать SSE2 инструкции movnti.

Comment: @user7860670, если даже load/store будут использовать несколько машинных инструкций (и не будут атомарными), то это по сути ни на что в рамках темы данного вопроса не влияет (т.е. изменение переменной будет видно из другого потока (или callback-а в том же потоке)).  Собственно, как и `movnti` (да, я не знал про них, читающих и пишущих в обход кэша), если этот механизм будет симметрично использован разными потоками.