# Вопрпос по разделяемой переменной при параллельных вычислениях

Tags: c++, многопоточность, cpu

Решил я таки попытаться реализовать систему параллельных вычислений, похожую на так называемую Job System, что описана в известной книге Джейсона Грегори по игровым движкам. А так как опыта в многопоточности у меня нет, то в процессе написания возникают вопросы.

Постараюсь выдать тут концентрат одного такого назревшего вопроса. Допустим, имеются два потока. Первый ждёт некоторой задачи, в бесконечном цикле проверяя разделяемую переменную-указатель на класс этой задачи. Этот указатель объявлен, разумеется, как volatile, чтобы применялось обращение к памяти, а не к регистрам. Вот псевдокод:

```
//В потоке 1
CWorkThread::MainFunc()
{
    ...
    while (!m_pExpectJob);   //ждём задачу (указатель m_pExpectJob является volatile)
    m_pExpectJob->JobFunc(); //выполняем задачу
    ...
}
```

Второй поток, соответственно, заносит эту задачу в поле m_pExpectJob ожидающего потока, пускай как-то так:

```
//В потоке 2
CWorkThread::MainFunc()
{
    ...
    pWaitThread->m_pExpectJob = m_pJobQueue->TakeJob(); //передаём задачу на выполнение
    ...
}
```

Собственно вопрос: насколько работоспособен такой подход на многоядерных процессорах?

Я как рассуждаю: операции непосредственного чтения и записи в память (инструкция mov) уже сами по себе неделимы, а значит дополнительная синхронизация с помощью каких-либо мьютексов или атомиков по идее не нужна. Однако так ли это на самом деле? Может ли одновременное обращение к данной переменной из разных ядер (одно на чтение, второе на запись) привести к сбою? Или могут ли проблемы возникнуть с кэшем (L1 и L2, насколько я знаю, являются локальными для ядер, а значит в основную память корректное значение вроде как может и не попасть)?

Может всё-таки лучше использовать атомарные операции, в которых есть блокировка шины (префикс lock), например такие, как InterlockedIncrement()? Однако, блокировка шины в цикле, как я полагаю, может привести к потере производительности, если цикл затянется. По-этому и интересует работоспособность варианта без блокировки.

Comment: Ну во-первых, переменная `m_pExpectJob` должна быть с атрибутом `volatile`. Иначе компилятор не будет смотреть постоянно туда и сделает вам бесконечный цикл. В принципе, если задача только ожидать задачу, то и такое сойдёт. Но вот если, бы переменная не влазила в регистр процессора, то была-бы лажа. Вы бы выполняли "пол-задачи" *(адреса ещё не дописали до-конца)*. Надёжнее всё-таки использовать **atomic** переменные.

Comment: Этот подход полностью неработоспособен, `volatile` не делает обращение к переменной из нескольких потоков безопасным. Все ваши рассуждения неверные. Используйте примитивы синхронизации из стандартной библиотеки или же atomic оттуда же.

Comment: @AlexGlebe насчёт volatile понятно, я об этом упомянул (сейчас добавил ещё в комментарий к псевдокоду, чтобы было заметнее). В этом случае гарантировано, что компилятор не будет кэшировать эту переменную в регистр (в GCC - точно, я проверял). Для большей уверенности в этом можно сделать присваивание и цикл ожидания ассемблерной вставкой. Тут вопрос стоит так: можно ли считать инструкции mov [mem],reg и cmp  [mem],0 как atomic? Однако, я вычитал, что для этих инструкций не применим префикс lock. И по всей видимости они не блокируют шину данных...

Comment: @user7860670 да, сам по себе volatile не делает обращения к переменной потокобезопасными. Однако объявление sometype volatile var даёт гарантию, что по выражению var = value значение value запишется непосредственно в память, в которой находится переменая var, а не в регистр, которому оптимизатор поставил в соответствие переменную var. То же самое и на чтение. Однако есть ещё кэш, который может спутать карты, вот с этим я пока не разобрался...

Comment: Если используете широко распространенные архитектуры (x86, arm, ...), то кэши когерентны, изменение данных в одном кэше вызовет изменение в другом при чтении в другом  кэше с того же адреса. [Другой вопрос](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOESI), если у нас более 2-х процессорных элементов с кэшем и в 2-х из них переменная одновременно меняется, то какое из этих изменений увидит 3-й кэш? (первые 2 к этому  моменту будут синхронизированы и будут содержать одно из 2-х значений)

Comment: *"Однако объявление sometype volatile var даёт гарантию, что по выражению var = value значение value запишется непосредственно в память, в которой находится переменая var, а не в регистр,"* - ничего подобного. см [Volatile для согласованности кешей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055628/volatile-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: @user7860670, ну, если я правильно понял смысл volatile, то он гарантирует лишь одно: выражение `var = value` будет компилироваться в инструкцию, вида `mov ds:var, value`, в то время, как без volatile результатом может стать, например, `mov ebx,value`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Необходимые оговорки

Во-первых, если тип `m_pExpectJob` не объявлен, как атомарный тип, то с точки зрения C++ нет никаких гарантий, что запись в него будет атомарной, а следовательно попытка конкурентного чтения/записи в него из разных потоков — это, вообще говоря, гонка данных, что является UB. Так что для дальнейших рассуждений будем считать, что наша реализация (компилятор/платформа) даёт некоторые дополнительные гарантии, что простые чтение/запись `m_pExpectJob` атомарны.

Во-вторых, это «горячее» ожидание на процессоре: оно, конечно, имеет право на существование, но надо иметь в виду, что это, вообще говоря, достаточно расточительно, а на однопроцессорной системе — вообще бессмысленно; так что в таком виде на практике это применяется не так часто.

#### Что может пойти не так

С одной переменной, с учётом оговорок, IRL почти всегда будет всё работать, как и ожидается. Проблемы начинаются если есть ещё один разделяемый объект. Обычно, например, мы передаём не только задачу, но и данные для неё:

```
class CJob {
  void* data;
  // ...
};
volatile CJob *m_pExpectJob

// ...

// Поток1

CJob *job = m_pJobQueue->TakeJob();
job->data = my_data;              // (1)
pWaitThread->m_pExpectJob = job;  // (2)

// ...

// Поток2

while(!m_pExpectJob);             // (3)
m_pExpectJob->JobFunc(job->data); // (4)
```

Так вот, на некоторых архитектурах это может привести к тому, что `job->data` в (4) не будет инициализирована. На x86 с её сильной моделью памяти всё в данном случае должно быть нормально, но на каком-нибудь arm'е это вполне вероятное событие.

Да, т.к. `m_pExpectJob` объявлен как `volitile`, то компилятор, конечно, не сможет переставить инструкции (1) и (2), но он и не сделает ни каких дополнительных действий, дабы этого не сделал процессор через механизм [внеочередного исполнения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Нарваться на проблемы вызванные внеочередным исполнением в x86, вообще говоря, тоже можно, но [сложнее](https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/).

Дабы всё это гарантированно предотвратить необходимо добавить [*барьеры памяти*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) (*fence*). В корректном варианте пример выше будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
std::atomic<CJob*> m_pExpectJob;

// ...

// Поток1

CJob *job = m_pJobQueue->TakeJob();
job->data = my_data;
pWaitThread->m_pExpectJob.store(job, std::memory_order_release);

// ...

// Поток2
CJob *job = 0
do {
  job = m_pExpectJob.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
} while(!job);
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
m_pExpectJob->JobFunc(job->data);
```

Подробности, о том, какие бывают барьеры и в чём между ними разница я уже описывал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052530/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/1052779#1052779).

---

> в которых есть блокировка шины (префикс lock), например такие, как InterlockedIncrement()? Однако, блокировка шины в цикле, как я полагаю, может привести к потере производительности, если цикл затянется.

На x86 для чтения переменной блокировка шины не обязательна: обычный `mov` в регистр с выравненного адреса вполне атомарен. Если целиться под x86, то можно не парится с release-acqure семантикой и лепить всё «как есть» обычными `std::atomic` с `std::memory_order_seq_cst`: код будет почти такой же (не считая, разве что, записи), но корректный и переносимый.

На каком-нибудь arm'е `volatile`-варианты будут работать некорректно, а в стандартном варианте «без излишеств» — не оптимально... там всё это веселье с release-acqure используется во всю силу.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! И так, по-порядку: 1) Про кроссплатформенность и arm, полагаю, мне пока рано думать, тут бы с родной x86 до конца разобраться. Так что задачу пока ставлю так: максимально эффективно реализовать параллелизм на архитектуре x86. 2) Учитывая вами сказанное, будет ли тогда работать следующего вида код: для ждущего потока `L: cmp [pExceptJob_64byteAligned],0; jz L`, для пишущего потока: `mov eax,[pJob]; xchg [pExceptJob_64byteAligned],eax`, при условии, что ждущий поток один, а пишущих одновременно может быть несколько?

Comment: 1) без этого просто непонятно, почему в плюсах это устроено так как устроено и зачем этим заморачиваться, когда всё и так работает; 2) если пишущие заносят не ноль и возможны потери, то в принципе сойдёт, хотя я бы использовал `L: mov eax,[pExceptJob_64byteAligned]; jz L` — после `mov` содержимое переменной можно не читать второй раз, а использовать содержимое `eax`; и для пишущих: `mov eax,[pJob]; mov [pExceptJob_64byteAligned],eax` — блокировка шины тут ИМХО не нужна, хотя это особо погоды и не делает.